# ARM Template - Deploying function using MSDeploy with zipped code in Azure Storage Blob

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-resource-manager, msdeploy

I'm trying to deploy an Azure function for which the zipped contents have been placed in a blob in another subscription and resource group. The function app is deployed, but there's no function under it, and **MSDeploy fails with a timeout** -

```json
"provisioningOperation": "Create",
  "provisioningState": "Failed",
  "timestamp": "2021-07-23T15:10:45.9602877Z",
  "duration": "PT2H11.3363166S",
  "serviceRequestId": "17787274-8592-465b-a11e-10aada76286e",
  "statusCode": "RequestTimeout",
  "statusMessage": {
    "error": {
      "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
      "message": "The resource provision operation did not complete within the allowed timeout period."
    }
  },
  "targetResource": {
    "id": "/subscriptions/<sub-id>/resourceGroups/rg-7ND96/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/FnAppubjba74tmczo4/Extensions/MSDeploy",
    "resourceName": "FnAppubjba74tmczo4/MSDeploy",
    "resourceType": "Microsoft.Web/sites/Extensions"
```

I'm assuming this is happening because MSDeploy is unable to access the zip file in the blob. I haven't provided any explicit access, and I'm unable to figure out how to do that. Below is my ARM template for the function app -

```json
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[variables('functionAppName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "kind": "functionapp",
      "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('functionAppName')]",
        "clientAffinityEnabled": false
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('appInsightsName'))]"
      ],
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
          "name": "appsettings",
          "type": "config",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionAppName'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('appInsightsName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "AzureWebJobsStorage": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';EndpointSuffix=', environment().suffixes.storage, ';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value)]",
            "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~3",
            "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
            "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';EndpointSuffix=', environment().suffixes.storage, ';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value)]",
            "FileStorageAccountConnectionString": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';EndpointSuffix=', environment().suffixes.storage, ';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value)]",
            "FileShareName": "[variables('fileShareName')]",
            "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "[reference(resourceId('microsoft.insights/components/', variables('appInsightsName')), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "MSDeploy",
          "type": "Extensions",
          "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('functionAppName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "packageUri": "https://storage-name.blob.core.windows.net/Function.zip",
            "appOffline": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Can I provide the function app access to the blob using managed identity dynamically in the ARM template before the MSDeploy resource runs? If not, can I generate a SAS token in the ARM template for access?

UPADTE -
I went to the check the logs in the deployed function app in **..\home\LogFiles\SiteExtensions\MSDeploy** - appManagerLog.xml -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entries>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:13:08.5448175+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>Downloading package path 'Function.zip' from blob 'https://storage-name.blob.core.windows.net'</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:13:09.0604383+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>No parameters were populated.</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:13:09.0604383+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>AppOffline enabled</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:13:09.0604383+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>Calling SyncTo() on package.</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:13:09.3104411+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>Adding file (.\FunctionApp.csproj).</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:13:09.3104411+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>Adding file (.\FunctionApp.csproj).</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:13:09.3729946+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>Deleting file (.\host.json).</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:13:09.3729946+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>Deleting file (.\host.json).</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:13:09.4199523+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>Adding file (.\local.settings.json).</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:13:09.4199523+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>Adding file (.\local.settings.json).</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:13:09.4823395+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>Adding directory (.\Models).</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:13:09.4823395+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>Adding directory (.\Models).</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:13:09.529223+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>Adding file (.\Models\RequestModel.cs).</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:13:09.529223+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>Adding file (.\Models\RequestModel.cs).</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:13:09.5917233+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>Adding file (.\Models\State.cs).</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:13:09.5917233+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>Adding file (.\Models\State.cs).</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:13:09.654252+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>Adding file (.\Models\StateInfo.cs).</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:13:09.654252+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>Adding file (.\Models\StateInfo.cs).</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:13:09.716655+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>Adding file (.\ResponseFunction.cs).</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:13:09.716655+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>Adding file (.\ResponseFunction.cs).</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:13:09.8729031+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>Total Changes: 8 (7 added, 1 deleted, 0 updated, 0 parameters changed, 7989 bytes copied)</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:13:09.8729031+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>[Information] [user: F8C3B4564BD880EEFBE19EBA84667977B183FC6B] [324886c5-3416-4866-b8b4-5c3a2ed83394] WebDeploy operation complete. Performing post-deployment operations.</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:13:10.6130904+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>[Verbose] [user: F8C3B4564BD880EEFBE19EBA84667977B183FC6B] Begin HttpPost https://adobefnappubjba74tmczo4.azurewebsites.net/admin/host/synctriggers, x-ms-request-id: 324886c5-3416-4866-b8b4-5c3a2ed83394</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:16:47.9939772+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>Downloading package path 'Function.zip' from blob 'https://storage-name.blob.core.windows.net'</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:16:48.0721032+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>No parameters were populated.</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:16:48.0721032+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>AppOffline enabled</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:16:48.0721032+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>Calling SyncTo() on package.</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:16:48.1502509+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>Deleting file (.\host.json).</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:16:48.1502509+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>Deleting file (.\host.json).</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:16:48.2596268+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>Total Changes: 1 (0 added, 1 deleted, 0 updated, 0 parameters changed, 0 bytes copied)</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:16:48.2596268+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>[Information] [user: F8C3B4564BD880EEFBE19EBA84667977B183FC6B] [ae7d2678-ec79-476b-8e72-e3a4e4cc0d70] WebDeploy operation complete. Performing post-deployment operations.</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:16:48.3221254+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>[Verbose] [user: F8C3B4564BD880EEFBE19EBA84667977B183FC6B] Begin HttpPost https://adobefnappubjba74tmczo4.azurewebsites.net/admin/host/synctriggers, x-ms-request-id: ae7d2678-ec79-476b-8e72-e3a4e4cc0d70</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:21:42.6541756Z" type="Message">
        <message>Downloading package path 'Function.zip' from blob 'https://storage-name.blob.core.windows.net'</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:21:42.7318456Z" type="Message">
        <message>No parameters were populated.</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:21:42.7318456Z" type="Message">
        <message>AppOffline enabled</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:21:42.7318456Z" type="Message">
        <message>Calling SyncTo() on package.</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:21:42.8099044Z" type="Message">
        <message>Deleting file (.\host.json).</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:21:42.8099044Z" type="Message">
        <message>Deleting file (.\host.json).</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:21:42.8880416Z" type="Message">
        <message>Total Changes: 1 (0 added, 1 deleted, 0 updated, 0 parameters changed, 0 bytes copied)</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:21:42.8880416Z" type="Message">
        <message>[Information] [user: F8C3B4564BD880EEFBE19EBA84667977B183FC6B] [6b7c0ba0-8504-4525-9f99-a5e7d787693f] WebDeploy operation complete. Performing post-deployment operations.</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2021-07-23T15:21:42.9505549Z" type="Message">
        <message>[Verbose] [user: F8C3B4564BD880EEFBE19EBA84667977B183FC6B] Begin HttpPost https://adobefnappubjba74tmczo4.azurewebsites.net/admin/host/synctriggers, x-ms-request-id: 6b7c0ba0-8504-4525-9f99-a5e7d787693f</message>
    </entry>
</entries>
```

From the logs it appears that MSDeploy does have access to the blob since all the folders are being read.
However, my deployment fails and when I go to the Azure portal to the deployed function app, there are no functions under it.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: Hi @kruti Joshi, How much size of Zip code are you used to deploy?

Comment: The size is just 1.3Mb.

Comment: you might try tweeting @AzureSupport on this one...

Answer (score 1):

Your package URI should contain a Shared Access Signature (SAS)

```
"packageUri": "https://storage-name.blob.core.windows.net/Function.zip?sv=yourSAS",
```

> For that, in Azure Storage Explorer, create a Shared Access Signature
> (SAS) token for the storage container, and then append the token to
> the WDP URLs. Make a note of the package URLs for later use in ARM
> templates.

In your case the wdp is a zip file, same same but different.

A SAS URI looks like this:

```
https://contoso.blob.core.windows.net/container01?sv=2020-04-08&st=2021-03-02T00%3A30%3A33Z&se=2020-03-03T00%3A30%3A33Z&sr=c&sp=rl&sig=z9VFdWffrV6FXU51T8b8HVfipZPOpYOFLXuQw6wfkFY%3F
```

> In the Select Resource panel of the Connect to Azure Storage dialog,
> select the resource you want to connect to. Select Shared access
> signature (SAS) and select Next. Enter a display name for your
> connection and the SAS URI for the resource.  Select Next. Review your
> connection information in the Summary panel.  If the connection
> information is correct, select Connect.

From [microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows)